# Firebase Storage gives StorageTaskEventType.failure for PNG files (trying to upload iOS screenshots)

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, flutter-layout

I am using Flutter and Firebase Storage Plugin to upload images from camera as well as from the gallery.

It is working great for any images which are taken by camera. But if I am trying to upload a screenshot (which is PNG instead of JPEG), I get the following error `StorageTaskEventType.failure`.

Is it possible, that PNGs are somehow restricted or any idea what I am doing wrong?

The following code is used:

```
    ImageProperties properties =
        await FlutterNativeImage.getImageProperties(imageFile.path);

    File compressedFile = await FlutterNativeImage.compressImage(imageFile.path,
        quality: 50,
        targetWidth: 900,
        targetHeight: (properties.height * 900 / properties.width).round()
        );
    String fileName = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString() + '.jpg';
    StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child('groups')
        .child(widget.groupId)
        .child('messageContent')
        .child(fileName);
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(compressedFile);
    StorageTaskSnapshot storageTaskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
    await storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadUrl) {
      imageUrl = downloadUrl;
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
        _handleSubmitted(imageUrl: imageUrl);
      });
    }, onError: (err) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: The SDK doesn't care at all about the type of file it's uploading.  Neither does the storage bucket.  The only thing that might care is any security rules that you have defined for your project that might reject an upload based on its type.

Comment: Try not to name the file with a .jpg. It messes things up a bit sometimes. Use a conversion algorithm later if you really want to convert it to jpg.

Comment: ...same error...

Comment: The issue seems to be related to this image compressor, which seems not to be able to compress PNGs.